# Ajuda com Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:

Tags: java, swing, eventos

Estou concluindo um código em java mas deparei com o erro acima e não estou conseguindo resolver.
Quando marco o checkbox os campos são formatados, quando desmarco recebo a exceção acima.
Alguém sabe me dizer onde estou errando:

Vou deixar as classes abaixo.

classe frame

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;   
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SalarioFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel painelTopo;
    private JPanel painelCentro;
    private JPanel painelFundo;
    private JLabel lblSalarioBruto;
    private JTextField txtSalarioBruto;
    private JButton btnCalcular;
    private JCheckBox chkFormatar;
    private JLabel lblBaseInss;
    private JLabel lblDescInss;
    private JLabel lblBaseIrpf;
    private JLabel lblDescIrpf;
    private JTextField txtBaseInss;
    private JTextField txtDescInss;
    private JTextField txtBaseIrpf;
    private JTextField txtDescIrpf;
    private JLabel lblSalarioLiq;
    private JTextField txtSalarioLiq;

    public SalarioFrame() {
        iniciarElementos();
        configurarFrame();
        criarEvento();
        montarFrame();
    }

    /*
     * Criando eventos
     */
    private void criarEvento() {
        btnCalcular.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    if (txtSalarioBruto.getText().length() < 1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor preencher o campo Salário Bruto.");
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor preencher o campo Salário Bruto.");
                    return;
                }

                double salarioBruto = 0.0;

                try {
                    salarioBruto = Double.parseDouble(txtSalarioBruto.getText());
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor preencher o campo Salário Bruto com Número.");
                    return;
                }

                double[] valoresCalculados = SalarioClasse.ValorCalculo(salarioBruto);
                txtBaseInss.setText(String.valueOf(valoresCalculados[0]));
                txtDescInss.setText(String.valueOf(valoresCalculados[1]));
                txtBaseIrpf.setText(String.valueOf(valoresCalculados[2]));
                txtDescIrpf.setText(String.valueOf(valoresCalculados[3]));
                txtSalarioLiq.setText(String.valueOf(valoresCalculados[4]));
                painelCentro.revalidate();
            }
        });

        chkFormatar.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                try {
                    if (!(Double.parseDouble(txtSalarioLiq.getText()) > 0.0)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Antes de formatar, por favor informar um Salário Bruto e clicar no botão [Calcular]");
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Antes de formatar, por favor informar um Salário Bruto e clicar no botão [Calcular]");
                    return;
                }

                String salarioBruto = "", salarioLiquido = "", descontoInss = "", descontoIrpf = "", baseInss = "",
                        baseIrpf = "";

                if (chkFormatar.isSelected()) {

                    NumberFormat formatoMoeda = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
                    salarioBruto = formatoMoeda.format(Double.parseDouble(txtSalarioBruto.getText()));
                    salarioLiquido = formatoMoeda.format(Double.parseDouble(txtSalarioLiq.getText()));
                    descontoInss = formatoMoeda.format(Double.parseDouble(txtDescInss.getText()));
                    descontoIrpf = formatoMoeda.format(Double.parseDouble(txtDescIrpf.getText()));
                    baseInss = formatoMoeda.format(Double.parseDouble(txtBaseInss.getText()));
                    baseIrpf = formatoMoeda.format(Double.parseDouble(txtBaseIrpf.getText()));

                    txtSalarioBruto.setText(salarioBruto);
                    txtSalarioLiq.setText(salarioLiquido);
                    txtDescInss.setText(descontoInss);
                    txtDescIrpf.setText(descontoIrpf);
                    txtBaseInss.setText(baseInss);
                    txtBaseIrpf.setText(baseIrpf);

                } else {
                    salarioBruto = txtSalarioBruto.getText();
                    salarioLiquido = txtSalarioLiq.getText();
                    descontoInss = txtDescInss.getText();
                    descontoIrpf = txtDescIrpf.getText();
                    baseInss = txtBaseInss.getText();
                    baseIrpf = txtBaseIrpf.getText();

                    txtSalarioBruto.setText(salarioBruto);
                    txtSalarioLiq.setText(salarioLiquido);
                    txtDescInss.setText(descontoInss);
                    txtDescIrpf.setText(descontoIrpf);
                    txtBaseInss.setText(baseInss);
                    txtBaseIrpf.setText(baseIrpf);
                }
                painelCentro.revalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Montando Frame
     */
    private void montarFrame() {
        painelTopo.add(lblSalarioBruto);
        painelTopo.add(txtSalarioBruto);
        painelTopo.add(btnCalcular);
        painelTopo.add(chkFormatar);
        painelCentro.add(lblBaseInss);
        painelCentro.add(txtBaseInss);
        painelCentro.add(lblDescInss);
        painelCentro.add(txtDescInss);
        painelCentro.add(lblBaseIrpf);
        painelCentro.add(txtBaseIrpf);
        painelCentro.add(lblDescIrpf);
        painelCentro.add(txtDescIrpf);
        painelFundo.add(lblSalarioLiq);
        painelFundo.add(txtSalarioLiq);
    }

    /**
     * Iniciar Elementos
     */
    private void iniciarElementos() {
        painelTopo = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        lblSalarioBruto = new JLabel("Salário Bruto:");
        txtSalarioBruto = new JTextField(10);
        btnCalcular = new JButton("Calcular");
        chkFormatar = new JCheckBox("Formatar");
        painelCentro = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        painelCentro = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        lblBaseInss = new JLabel("Base INSS");
        txtBaseInss = new JTextField();
        txtBaseInss.setEnabled(false);
        lblDescInss = new JLabel("Desconto INSS");
        txtDescInss = new JTextField(10);
        txtDescInss.setEnabled(false);
        lblBaseIrpf = new JLabel("Base IRPF");
        txtBaseIrpf = new JTextField(10);
        txtBaseIrpf.setEnabled(false);
        lblDescIrpf = new JLabel("Desconto IRPF");
        txtDescIrpf = new JTextField(10);
        txtDescIrpf.setEnabled(false);
        painelFundo = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        lblSalarioLiq = new JLabel("Salário Liquido:");
        txtSalarioLiq = new JTextField(10);
        txtSalarioLiq.setEnabled(false);
    }

    /*
     * Configurando Frame
     */
    private void configurarFrame() {
        this.setTitle("Calculador de salário");
        this.setSize(400, 180);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        this.add(painelTopo, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        this.add(painelCentro, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(painelFundo, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }
}
```

classe Salario

```
public class SalarioClasse {

    public static double[] ValorCalculo(double salarioBruto) {

        double[] valorCalculo = new double[5];
        valorCalculo[0] = salarioBruto;

        //calculo INSS
        if(salarioBruto <= 1659.38) 
            valorCalculo[1] = salarioBruto * 0.8;

        if(salarioBruto >= 1659.39 && salarioBruto <= 2765.66)
            valorCalculo[1] = salarioBruto * 0.9;

        if(salarioBruto >= 2765.67 && salarioBruto <= 5531.31) 
            valorCalculo[1] = salarioBruto * 0.11;

        if(valorCalculo[1] > 608.45)
            valorCalculo[1] = 608.45;

        //salario liquido
        valorCalculo[2] = salarioBruto - valorCalculo[1];

        //calculo IRPF
        if(valorCalculo[2] <= 1903.98)
            valorCalculo[3] = 0.0;

        if(valorCalculo[2] >= 1903.99 && valorCalculo[2] <= 2826.65)
            valorCalculo[3] = ((valorCalculo[2] * 7.5) / 100) - 142.80;

        if(valorCalculo[2] >= 2826.66 && valorCalculo[2] <= 3751.05)
            valorCalculo[3] = ((valorCalculo[2] * 15) / 100) - 354.80;

        if(valorCalculo[2] >= 3751.06 && valorCalculo[2] <= 4664.68)
            valorCalculo[3] = ((valorCalculo[2] * 22.5) / 100) - 636.13;

        if(valorCalculo[2] > 4664.68)
            valorCalculo[3] = ((valorCalculo[2] * 27.5) / 100) - 869.36;        

        valorCalculo[4] = salarioBruto - valorCalculo[1] - valorCalculo[3];

        return valorCalculo;
    }
}
```

classe Main

```
public class SalarioMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        new SalarioFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Precisa mesmo desformatar ao desmarcar o campo? Ou você quer ignorar quando desmarcar?

Comment: Esse `catch (NullPointerException ex)` não era para ser `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa acho que não, testei aqui, esse cach evita validar se o campo tiver vazio.

Comment: O problema é facil de resolver, mas falta o autor informar melhor como o programa deveria funcionar neste caso.

Comment: No caso preciso desformatar. Quando desmarcar quero tirar o formato moeda, mas quando desmarco para desformatar gera a exceção.

Comment: @Josano para isso, você precisa salvar todos os valores dos campos antes de formatar. Você está substituindo tudo, ai não volta mesmo pros valores antigos.

Comment: Humm seria o caso de criar as variaveis fora para guardar o valor e reaproveitar depois? Tenho pouca experiência com java e fiquei meio sem norte ao tentar solucionar.

Comment: @Josano é uma solução também.